# How do I use mysql column contents as index (key) to php array in mySql query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to know how or if I can use the content of a column in mysql as a key (index) to a php array within the mysql query.

Example:

Column name: period

Column contents: (one of) 'Year','Month','Fortnight','Week','Hour','Day'

My php array:

```
$x = array(
'Year' => 1,
'Month' => 12,
'Fortnight' => 26,
'Week' => 52,
'Hour' => 1872,
'Day' => 365
);
```

Another variable $y can be any number (say < 1,000,000)

I want to write a WHERE (or HAVING) condition such as...

```
WHERE '$x[`period`]' * '$y' > 12345
```

E.g. when the contents of **period** = 'Month', $y should be multiplied by 12 before being tested to be > 12345

What is the best (most efficient) way to do this, other than (say) a long CASE conditional?

Thank you

Comment: Can you store the `$x` values in a mysql table? Because the way it is right now, you're either gonna have to fetch the `perioid` column beforehand, or you have to somehow squish the `$x` values into the query...

Comment: Thanks Manuel Otto.  That's given me an idea... I guess I could create/write a temporary table... but I wonder if CASE might not be simpler and more efficient way?

Comment: I think a case, a separate table, or a php array are pretty much your 3 options

Comment: Thanks Strawberry... I guess it looks that way... CASE for a small dataset and a table for a big one.

Answer (score 0):

i have write demo query

```
<?php
$x = array(
'Year' => 1,
'Month' => 12,
'Fortnight' => 26,
'Week' => 52,
'Hour' => 1872,
'Day' => 365
);
$y=10;

$sql="select * from table where ".$x['Month']*$y." > 12345" ;

echo $sql;
```

in `$x[]` select your value to multiply

Comment: Thank you Bhargav but the solution uses $x['Month'] where 'Month' does not vary.  I need the index (key) to $x to be a variable set by the contents of the period column in that db record.

Comment: you can share more info about your query

Comment: I'm sorry Bhargav, I don't know what more I can share.  Perhaps if you would tell me what more you need from me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` instead of php array:

```
<?php
$y = 100;

$sql = "select * from tablename
where (case `period`
  when 'Year' then 1
  when 'Month' then 12
  when 'Fortnight' then 26
  when 'Week' then 52
  when 'Hour' then 1872
  when 'Day' then 365
end) * {$y} > 12345";
```

Comment: Thank you vher.  I did mention CASE in my post saying, "other than (say) a long CASE conditional?"  I was wondering if there was another (more elegant and/or efficient)  way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $y = 10;
  $period = "Month";

  $x = array(
    'Year' => 1,
    'Month' => 12,
    'Fortnight' => 26,
    'Week' => 52,
    'Hour' => 1872,
    'Day' => 365
  );

  $sql="select * from table where ".($x[$period] * $y)." > 12345" ;

  echo $sql;
```

Comment: Thanks just_a_simple_guy but the challenge is to make the index (key) of array $x the value stored the mysql column named period.  So it varies with every record.